# Maximal ideals in the algebra of continuously differentiable functions on [0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, commutative-algebra, banach-algebras

This is an exercise in Rudin's Functional Analysis, in the chapter on commutative Banach algebras. My (uneducated) guess was that every homomorphism on $C^{1}[0,1]$ is an evaluation at some point of [0,1]. The imitation of the proof for finding the homomorphisms on $C[0,1]$, as in Simmons, fails as taking the moduli of functions does not preserve differentiability. I would be grateful for hints on this.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  It will help us to answer it if you state the question precisely, together with any relevant definitions.  You've done a great job describing your work so far.

Comment: Do you assume that the homomorphism is continuous? If so, once you know its value on $f(x)=x$, you know it on all polynomials. And polynomials are dense.

Comment: Here is the precise question: (Exercise 9(a), Chapter 11: Commutative Banach Algebras, Functional Analysis, W L Rudin): Show that $C^{1}[0,1]$ with norm given by $\|f\|= \|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}$ is a semisimple commutative Banach algebra. Find its maximal ideal space. We know there is a one-one correspondence between maximal ideals of an algebra and its non-zero complex homomorphisms (here, complex homomorphisms are complex valued multiplicative linear functionals. These are always continuous).

Comment: So to find the maximal ideal space of the algebra it suffices to find all complex homomorphisms on the algebra. My question is- are all such homomorphims of the form of evaluations at points of $[0,1]$? We know this is true in the case of $C(X)$ for any compact Hausdorff space $X$. A proof of this can be found in Example 11.13 (a) of the same chapter of Rudin's book. If we try to imitate this proof, we construct a function $g=|f_{1}|^{2}+...+|f_{n}|^{2}$, where the $f_{i}$s are continuously differentiable. While $g$ is continuous, it need not be differentiable since the mod function is not.

Comment: I do not know if my guess is correct at all. Hence the request for help!

Comment: modulus may not be differentiable, but modulus squared is

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, every (unital) homomorphism on $C^1([0,1])$ is an evaluation homomorphism.

**Proof 1:** Let $x\in C^1([0,1])$ the identity, i.e. $x(t) = t$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Let $\varphi \colon C^1([0,1]) \to \mathbb{C}$ a (unital) algebra homomorphism, and $z := \varphi(x)$. Then $z \in [0,1]$ - otherwise $x - z$ would be invertible - and hence we have

$$\varphi(P) = P(z)$$

for all polynomials $P$. We will show below that the polynomials form a dense subspace of $C^1([0,1])$, then $\varphi(f) = f(z)$ for all $f\in C^1([0,1])$ follows by continuity.

To see that the subspace of polynomials is dense, let $f\in C^1([0,1])$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ arbitrary. By the Stone-Weierstraß theorem, there is a polynomial $P_1$ with $\lVert f' - P_1\rVert_\infty < \varepsilon/2$. Let

$$P(t) = f(0) + \int_0^t P_1(s)\,ds.$$

Then $\lVert f - P\rVert < \varepsilon$:

$$\begin{align}
\lvert f(t) - P(t)\rvert &= \left\lvert f(0) + \int_0^t f'(s)\,ds - \left(f(0) + \int_0^t P_1(s)\,ds\right) \right\rvert\\
&= \left\lvert \int_0^t (f'(s) - P_1(s))\,ds\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \int_0^t \lvert f'(s) - P_1(s)\rvert\,ds\\
&\leqslant t\cdot \lVert f' - P_1\rVert_\infty\\
&\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2},
\end{align}$$

whence $\lVert f - P\rVert = \lVert f-P\rVert_\infty + \lVert f' - P_1\rVert_\infty < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$.

---

**Proof 2:** Let $\mathfrak{a} \subsetneqq C^1([0,1])$ an ideal. Then

$$V(\mathfrak{a}) = \left\lbrace t \in [0,1] : \bigl(\forall f\in \mathfrak{a}\bigr)\bigl(f(t) = 0\bigr)\right\rbrace \neq \varnothing.$$

Suppose $V(\mathfrak{a}) = \varnothing$. Then, for every $t\in [0,1]$, there would be an $f_t \in \mathfrak{a}$ with $f_t(t) \neq 0$. Since $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal, $g_t \colon s \mapsto f_t(s)\cdot \overline{f_t(s)}$ also belongs to $\mathfrak{a}$, and there is an open neighbourhood $U_t$ of $t$ with $g_t(s) > 0$ for all $s \in U_t$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there are finitely many points $t_1,\dotsc,t_n$ such that

$$[0,1] = \bigcup_{k=1}^n U_{t_k}.$$

Since all $g_t$ are non-negative, and strictly positive on $U_t$,

$$g = \sum_{k=1}^n g_{t_k}$$

is strictly positive on all of $[0,1]$. But that means $g$ is a unit in $C^1([0,1])$, and hence $\mathfrak{a} = C^1([0,1])$, contradicting the assumption.

Let now $\varphi$ a (unital) homomorphism, and $\ker \varphi = \mathfrak{m} \subsetneqq C^1([0,1])$ the corresponding maximal ideal. Let $p \in V(\mathfrak{m})$. Then $\mathfrak{I}(p) = \left\lbrace f\in C^1([0,1]) : f(p) = 0\right\rbrace$ is a proper ideal containing $\mathfrak{m}$, and by maximality, $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{I}(p) = \ker \eta_p$, where $\eta_p$ is the evaluation homomorphism $f \mapsto f(p)$. Hence $\varphi = \eta_p$.

Comment: Why is $g_t \in \mathfrak a$ ? This would be true if either $\mathfrak a$ is closed under conjugation or if the conjugate of a functions is again continuously differentiable ? But conjugating does not preserve the $C^1$ property, I guess.

Comment: Complex conjugation is smooth (even real-analytic), therefore the conjugate of a continuously differentiable function is again continuously differentiable.

Comment: Okay, I see. I was confused about complex and real differentiable. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry for the bump but could you explain why $z \in [0,1]$ . I dont get the contradiction ur trying to make if that isnt true.

Comment: @Exc If $z \notin [0,1]$, then $x-z \colon t \mapsto t - z$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[0,1]$ that has no zero. Hence $h = \frac{1}{x-z} \colon t \mapsto \frac{1}{t-z}$ belongs to $C^1([0,1])$, and we have the contradiction $$\begin{aligned}1 &= \varphi(1) = \varphi\bigl(h\cdot(x - z)\bigr)\\ &= \varphi(h)\cdot \varphi(x-z) = \varphi(h)\cdot \bigl(\varphi(x) - z\varphi(1)\bigr)\\ &= \varphi(h)\cdot(z - z) = \varphi(h)\cdot 0 = 0.\end{aligned}$$