# Maximal ideals of $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, banach-algebras

What are the maximal ideals of $C^1[0,1]$?

We know that the maximal ideals of $C[0,1]$ are of the form $\{f:f(x)=0\}$ and we use the compactness of $[0,1]$ to prove this,but how do we find maximal ideals of $C^1[0,1]$?

This question is asked in our course on Banach Algebras.

Comment: what's the difference of $C^{1}[0,1]$ and $C[0,1]$? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I presume $C^1[0,1]$ is the space of $C^1$ functions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Ramanujan $C^1[0,1]$ is the set of all continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$  while $C[0,1]$ is the set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$

Comment: does the same method as you used for $C[0,1]$ also work for $C^1[0,1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to this question.
[Maximal ideals in the algebra of continuously differentiable functions on [0,1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379251/maximal-ideals-in-the-algebra-of-continuously-differentiable-functions-on-0-1)

In fact, by using the same method, we can prove that the maximal ideal space of $C^k[0,1]$ is $[0,1]$. The key point here is polynomials are dense in $C^k[0,1]$ for every integer $k$.